# How can I wrap an existing JSON file's contents as part of an object?

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

Since I don't know a lot about json terminology, I'm going to give an example:

Say I have a json:

```
{

   "var1": "foo",
   "var2": "bar",
   ...
}
```

How can I use `jq` to convert this to:

```
{
  "Variables":
  {
      "var1": "foo",
      "var2": "bar",
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `jq '{"Variables": .}' <in.json >out.json`

Comment: I'm 100% certain this has been asked before; looking for the duplicate instance.

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Comment: Huh. It may have been asked before, but I'm wondering if the prior OP deleted their question; it's being very resistant to being found. Going to add an answer for now; I'll delete it (or flag it community-wiki) later, if someone finds the prior instance of the question.

Comment: Maybe the `jq` tag wiki should have a list of FAQs so they're easier to find

Comment: @thatotherguy - the jq tag wiki does have a link to the jq FAQ, which is long enough as it is.  Maybe SO needs a better way to add keywords as well as "tags"?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Keep your points!  The matching question was difficult to find.

Comment: @peak I didn't mean for people to help themselves, but for regulars to find canonical QA for dedup purposes. The [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) does this, and I get a lot of use out of it.

Comment: @thatotherguy - I understand your point, but still think one FAQ is enough, at least for jq. Hopefully adding a few more keywords and/or key tags to SO Questions will nudge Google and/or SO's search engine over the finish line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a jq query, your existing input is `.`. Thus, you can wrap it inside a new object by putting a `.` in the location where you want your existing content to be:

```
jq '{"Variables": .}' <in.json >out.json
```